# Determine The State of MIC in android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, voice-recognition

can we determine the state of MIC that any type of Voice is going in to MIC?

Or

how [Voice Recognition APP](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html) decide that we have complete our word and it start it's process of searching words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading samples from input device (Microphone) and detecting a linear amplitude of a signal is one way.

There are more sophisticated ways to do this, like applying ["Fourier transform"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) and detecting amplitude of specific range of "voice" frequencies, but that is harder and requires some knowledge of signal processing.

---

You can read raw LPCM sample data using [AndroidRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I read sample from input device or any example..?

Comment: You can use AndroidRecord for this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

Comment: But if you're in the middle of a Voice Recognition activity, this could disrupt and void the entire thing... Surely there must be a bit somewhere that says "Microphone is mute".

Comment: Not sure what you mean under "discrupt and void the entire thing". But my understanding is that Voice Recognizer collects data untill it detects that incoming data does not contain human voice anymore (or any sounds, which is easier). After this is detected, it stops collecting the data and sends already collected data to analyzer.